# Is it OK to reference an out-of-scope local variable within the same function?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

In this code, I reference the local variable `b` even though it is out of scope. But I do it from within the same function so it's probably still on the stack, right? I ran the program and it worked but I'd like to know if it's guaranteed to work on all implementations.

```
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    int* a;
    {
        int b = 5;
        a = &b;
    }
    std::cout << *a;
}
```

Comment: This is the very definition of a *dangling pointer*.

Comment: Your example is too simple. There are many things you could do in a more realistic example before the cout statement that could change the stack, destroying the value. Very bad practice.

Comment: Do not be lulled into a false sense of security that it "can" work.  If `b` was an object that allocated resources (memory, opened a file, et. al.), and its dtor freed those resources (which it should), the state of the "object" referenced by `*a` would be truly garbage.

Comment: If you want guarantees that something will work you should follow the rules of the language. This clearly doesn't do that.

Comment: Well, I didn't see it that clearly. It seemed to me that yes, b's destructor would already be called, but how the compiler use that stack location for any other purpose? Doesn't it "allocate" the place when it enters the function and deallocate it when it leaves the function?

Comment: @PetrHudeček The rules of the language have no notion of "stack." It's just about object lifetimes, scope etc. Once an object's lifetime ends, it cannot be used, period.

Comment: That makes sense. One more question: Even if the language itself doesn't know about stacks, is it possible - in common implementations - that, in a more complex example, that the value of "b" would be overwritten?

Comment: @PetrHudeček: What may happen is that `b` is never on the stack at all. The optimizer of a compiler may examine your code, observe that `a` is never used before the block is exited, and therefore the assignment `a = &b` may be deleted from the program, and that leaves `b` never used, so `int b = 5;` may also be deleted. Then `std::cout << *a;` uses an `a` that has never been assigned a value.

Answer (score 10):

No, that's **not** guaranteed to work. `a` is dangling once the inner scope is exited, so any dereference of it results in Undefined Behaviour and nothing whatsoever is guaranteed.

Comment: Just a remark for language lawyers: It is **not** dereferencing `a` what results in UB, but the _lvalue-to-rvalue_ conversion. The statement `sizeof(*a);` is well-defined.

Comment: @MWid True. Then again, the operand of `sizeof` is unevaluated. I tried to think of a way to rephrase it without getting into too much obscure detail, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is not that `b` is out of **scope**. It is that the **lifetime** of `b` has ended. Scope is about where the **name** of an object is known. Lifetime is about when the object **exists** (within the computational model).

Technically, the object `b` does not exist when you reference it with `*a`. The bytes that were used to represent it might happen to be still unchanged in memory, and accessing them with `*a` might happen to work sometimes, especially if optimization is not turned on, but it is undefined behavior.

An object can still be accessible even though its name is not in scope. Here is an example of an object that is accessible during its lifetime even though it is not in scope:

```
void foo(void)
{
    int b;
    bar(&b);
}
```

In this code, the function `bar` may access `b`, even though it cannot see the name of `b` in `foo`. Although control leaves the block in which `b` is created, execution of the block is merely suspended, not terminated. So `b` continues to exist even while the function `bar` is executing. So `b` will be out of scope, but the access will be during its lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

The spec says

> An instance of each object with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) is associated with each entry into its block. Such an object exists and retains its last-stored value during the execution of the block and while the block is suspended (by a call of a function or receipt of a signal).

`b` is an object with automatic storage duration. So, when you are outside the object's block, the object does not exist anymore. You *can* jump *before* it and continue write to it, I believe, but not if you jump outside its block. That's too much stretching it.

Comment: "**jump before it**" here means jump from outside the block to the inside(before the declaration on the object) and then use the object? did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I put together this example to help demonstrate what's going on with memory allocation in a typical frame-based stack. See: [Is the stack variable deallocated when it goes out of scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109274/is-the-stack-variable-deallocated-when-it-goes-out-of-scope). That question was closed as a duplicate.

In `testerA`, we capture the address of our *local* variable `a` for future use. We do a similar thing with `testerB`, only this time we capture the address of the *second* integer variable, `b`. Notice that we overwrite the memory for `a` with the value `44` - calling it `f` in this function.

You can inspect these values immediately after calling the functions to observe what's going on. We're literally re-using the same memory addresses - but there's no guarantee what format the data is in from a prior function call.

### Inspecting the Stack

```
#include <iostream>

int* aPtr = nullptr;
int* bPtr = nullptr;

int testerA()
{
    int a = 3;
    aPtr = &a;
}

int testerB()
{
    int f = 44;
    int b = 5;
    bPtr = &b;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    testerA();
    int test1 = *aPtr;
    testerB();
    int test2 = *aPtr;
    int test3 = *bPtr;

    cout << "A: " << test1 << " -> " << test2 << endl;
    cout << "B: " << test3 << endl;

    cout << "aPtr: " << hex << aPtr << endl;
    cout << "bPtr: " << hex << bPtr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Output

```
A: 3 -> 44
B: 5
aPtr: 0x7fff9e58609c
bPtr: 0x7fff9e586098
```