# Is the stack variable deallocated when it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11

### **sample1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* aPtr = nullptr;

    {
        int a = 3;
        aPtr = &a;
    }

    std::cout << *aPtr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3
```

I am able to access `a` through `aPtr`.

1. Does that mean `a` is not deallocated even after it goes out of
   scope.
2. Does that mean `a` is deallocated only after the function in
   which it is defined unwinds.
3. Or is this an undefined behavior that currently outputs some value?

### **sampe2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Box
{
    Box(int a_)
        :a(a_)
    {}

    int getValue() const { return a;}

    ~Box()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int a;
};


int main()
{
    Box* boxPtr = nullptr;

    {
        Box box = 23;
        boxPtr = &box;
    }

    std::cout << boxPtr->getValue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Destructor called
23
```

I am able to access `box` through `boxPtr` even after destructor of `box` is called.

Comment: Undefined behaviour, both times.

Comment: That memory location still happens to point to the data, but it could be overwritten at any stage.

Comment: @Vivek btw, you don't have to give constructor parameters ugly names like `a_` since `Box(int a) : a(a) {}` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Looks like undefined behaviour, the variable should be deallocated in both cases.

Comment: @MartinCook it is ub because the pointer holds an invalid pointer value after its pointee goes out of scope. It doesn't matter what is at the location of that address.

Comment: @Swordfish yes I agree, but the reason it was still able to give the correct value is that the bytes in that memory location (by chance) weren't overwritten yet

Comment: @MartinCook What happens is UB. The compiler would also be allowed to emit an undefined opcode for such operation. Or make the program order some pizza ...

Comment: As mentioned it is undefined behavior but are you running in debug or release mode?

Comment: @Swordfish, we just use underscore (`a_`) after parameter name to differentiate parameter names from class variables. Also we use underscore before class variables (`_a`) which I haven't reflected in this sample program. Just a convention.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, in both cases you are facing undefined behavior (so anything is allowed to happen). The stack variables are destroyed as soon as they go out of scope, the memory occupied by them is freed, although usually it's not immediately overwritten (at least in simple cases like above), therefore the pointer pointing at such variable, might sometimes exhibit more or less "valid" properties (as in it looks like the object is still valid), despite it clearly dangling.